# Touching a plotSymbol in CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to run some code when the user clicks (or touches) a plotSymbol on mye graph created with Core Plot.

This does not work with scatterPlot:

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:    (NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index); 
}
```

But this works well when I use the barPlot:

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);
}
```

What's missing from my attempt to capture when the user clicks or touches on my scatterPlot?

Comment: hi am also trying to integrate this funtionality in my code, but when i add this method its not even getting called when we tap on barplot .please explain me clearly,about  implimentation of this method.thx in advance...

Answer (score 14):

You need to set the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` on your scatter plot. You should set it to match the size of your plot symbols or slightly larger if you need a bigger target to click.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Also worth noting is that you can set the plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection to your plot width/number of symbols so that its easier to select symbols when there are few of them, and but still possible to select a certain symbol when there are many of them.

Comment: Man I love just how everything is exposed to us in this framework. Well designed.

Answer (score 9):

Also, don't forget to set the CPScatterPlot's delegate to point to your object, or it won't get called.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting up your stuff at init time in a subclass of CPTGraphHostingView (say in initWithCoder coming from a xib), your hostedGraph property might get clobbered by Core Plot (at least as of 1.3), and so the tap handling will short-circuit.

https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=555

Needless to say this happened to me :-)  My workaround is to set the hostedGraph in my numberOfRecordsForPlot if it's not set already.